# Downcasting "obj" to underlying array type w/o type annotation

Tags: .net, types, casting, f#

I am working with some data that is read from a binary file, and can be one of several primitive types, e.g. int16, int32, single, double, etc.

For example, say I have 3 files:

- File A: contains all int16
- File B: contains all int32
- File C: contains all single

The header of each file has a code for the datatype, for instance, File A would have a header field `dtype: 0`, File B would have a header field `dtype: 1`, and File C would have a header field `dtype: 2`.

The files are a proprietary image format - imagine a Bitmap, but where the body of the bitmap could all be int16, int32, or single.

Given that I have read the data from a binary file, I use a pattern match to convert the binary data into the type specified by the file header.

Say I have an array/buffer containing n bytes read from a filestream:

```
let buffer: byte[] = … <-- read bytes into here
let container = new ResizeArray<obj>() //maintain same type in pattern match

let matchDatatype (dtype: int) = // Let's read File B
    match dtype with
    | 0 ->             
        let typeBuffer: int16[] = numBytesInFile/2 |> Array.zeroCreate
        while stream.Position < stream.Length do
            stream.Read(buffer, 0, numBytesInFile) |> ignore
            Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, typeBuffer, 0, numBytesInFile)
            typeBuffer |> Array.chunkBySize 8 |> container.Add
    | 1 -> // Reading int32 from File B
        let typeBuffer: int32[] = numBytesInFile/4 |> Array.zeroCreate
        while stream.Position < stream.Length do
            stream.Read(buffer, 0, numBytesInFile) |> ignore
            Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, typeBuffer, 0, numBytesInFile)
            typeBuffer |> Array.chunkBySize 8 |> container.Add
    | 2 -> ...
    ….
```

So if I read from File B, the header data code says "read these bytes as int32", some other stuff happens and I have a `ResizeArray<obj>` that contains an array of arrays (e.g. `int[][]`)

To get the array I need, I just slice the ResizeArray (`container.[0]`) and I get an `obj`.

I need to get this `obj` back into an array type. The problem is that since I am reading files of multiple possible types, I am having trouble generalizing my code to work across all of the different files. I know I can do `container.[0] :?> int[][]` if I know that the file will have all ints, but I don't know that at design time.

I know I can't store the type of the array as a let binding from GetType(), which further confuses how I should approach this (e.g. `container.[0] :?> container.[0].GetType()` doesn't work).

Using fsi, here is an example of what I am trying to do if I had read from File B (int):

```
> let someArray = [|[|0;1;2|];|[3;4;5|]|];; <-- say I read this from File B
  val it : int [] [] = [|[|0; 1; 2|];[|3; 4; 5|]|]

> container.Add(someArray)
  val it: unit = ()

> let arrObj = container.[0]
  val it : obj = [|[|0; 1; 2|];[|3; 4; 5|]|]

> arrObj.GetType().FullName;;
  val it : string = "System.Int32[][]"

> arrObj :?> int[][] <-- I can't know this at design time
  val it : int [] [] = [|[|0; 1; 2|];[|3; 4; 5|]|]
```

The last step is where the problem is occurring. The returned type object clearly shows that it knows that the array isn't an object - that it is in fact an `int[][]`. How can I programmatically/dynamically perform this downcast without explicitly saying "downcast to `int[][]`?" I need this to work for the single[][] and int16[][] cases as well.

Or, is my whole approach flawed when it comes to having code that can flexibly read data of different types? My only other thought is to do some try-catch monstrosity but I feel like that isn't very idiomatic.

My previous work was all done in MATLAB, so this is a new problem for me since I could just eval strings and generate the code I need.

**edit**: Using Buffer.BlockCopy instead of BitConverter

**edit 2**: I see F# can define type aliases using `type`, where

```
[accessibility-modifier] type-abbreviation = type-name
```

However, this doesn't let me do something like `type ArrType = arrObj.GetType()`. The closest thing I can think of to what I think I need is a C-like typedef.

**edit 3**: I have been looking at something called dynamic instantiation using `Activator.CreateInstance()` - is this an instance where one might use this?

Comment: It is very unclear what you actually want to do. Are you reading elements all is different types, but then want to somehow make them one type? Or does every given file contain elements of just one type?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin every given file contains elements of just one type. I’ll try to clear it up in the question body.

Comment: What are you hoping to do with the result of the downcast?

Comment: @kvb Since the data in the files represents either a 3D or 4D array (the file format is a proprietary medical imaging format, if that helps), I would like to be able to perform computational operations on the arrays. Having the arrays as an obj doesn't let me do this, and the code cannot know whether the data is int16, int32, single, etc, until the file header is parsed (which I have no problem doing, luckily). I am concerned that coming from MATLAB/Mathematica is blinding me to some more idiomatic method, but it escapes me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something along the lines that [kaefer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2807130/kaefer) suggests would be most idiomatic.  Declare `container` as

```
let container = new ResizeArray<ArrayTypes>()
```

and now you can properly include each array in a strongly typed way.  Your `matchDataType` method can probably also be refactored to something more like

```
let add sz c = 
    let typeBuffer = numBytesInFile/sz |> Array.zeroCreate
    while stream.Position < stream.Length do
        stream.Read(buffer, 0, numBytesInFile) |> ignore
        Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, typeBuffer, 0, numBytesInFile)
        typeBuffer |> Array.chunkBySize 8 |> c |>  container.Add

let matchDatatype (dtype: int) = // Let's read File B
    match dtype with
    | 0 ->             
       add 2 I16
    | 1 -> // Reading int32 from File B
       add 4 I32
```

Then when you process your list you can do something like:

```
for t in container do
    match t with
    | I16 arr -> // do something with arr: int16[][]
    | I32 arr -> // do something with arr:   int[][]
    | F32 arr -> // do something with arr:single[][]
```

I think this is probably the cleanest approach, given how you've described your problem.

However, it *is* possible to do things dynamically, using a technique called "reflection":

```
type T() = 
    static member DoSomethingWithAnArray<'t>(arr:'t[][]) = arr.[0].[0]

let doSomethingWithAnArray (arr:obj) = 
    let meth = typeof<T>.GetMethod("DoSomethingWithAnArray")
    // for simplicity, I'm not actually checking that arr is an array of arrays
    // but you could use IsArray and GetArrayRank twice to be sure
    let elementType = arr.GetType().GetElementType().GetElementType()
    meth.MakeGenericMethod(elementType).Invoke(null, [|arr|])

doSomethingWithAnArray(box [|[|1.0|]|])
|> printfn "%A"
```

Here, we're dynamically calling `T.DoSomethingWithAnArray`, passing in an object and getting an object back out, even though this method has signature `'t[][] -> 't`.

Comment: I was definitely excited about the prospect of using a DU, but the problem I have with the DU types is that they're not enumerable, so I cant use the Item or GetSlice methods, and I don't think that DUs can be extended. Reflection was my original thought about working around the object problem, but reflecting on a 500mb array seemed like a possible performance bottleneck, at which point I wanted to just use reflection to downcast the entire array all at once. If there is a way to use IEnumerable with my DU cases then I think that would definitely be the best approach.

Comment: @normalchemist - You can't use those methods directly, but you can write a generic function of type `'a[][] -> something` and then use that function with whichever union case you've got (e.g. where I've got the `for` loop over the container, you would have cases like `| I16 arr -> myFunction arr`).

Comment: The one subtlety is that if your function has a type like `'a[][] -> 'a[]` then your three outputs will have different types (`int[]`, `int16[]`, and `single[]`), so you'll need to either box them or create a new union type for one-dimensional arrays.  But if the function has type `'a[][] -> float` or something like that you won't need to do that because you'll get a float in each branch.

Comment: So if I use the DU solution, I really don't have a choice but to dance around the types? It seems like if I use the DU solution, I lose any chance of working on the array with array methods, but if I use the reflection method then I'm going to be doing a ton of boxing and unboxing? Sorry if this is a tedious question - this is still a very new, nonparidigmatic methodology for me.

Comment: @normalchemist - That's not quite how I'd look at it.  Again, it might be helpful for you to expand upon what you're actually trying to do with the arrays in the end.  The easiest thing to do (if possible) is to make your array processing completely generic (that is, capable of operating on a `'t[][]` for _any_ type `'t`).  Then as you loop through your individual arrays you can perform one cast and then call the generic function on the result, without having to keep track of the intermediate heterogeneous list, which is what's causing you problems.

Comment: I think it finally clicked with me last night. I didn’t realize until I really played around with it that when I match on, say, “| I16 arr -> ...” that arr is actually going to be an array, not an I16, which means I can then work on it through the match. I actually understood the generic and inlining stuff for the most part, so just about anything that could work on arrays of different types is inlined, a static method, or has generic type constraints. I’ve come to think about pattern matches being like plumbing in this instance, which just tells the data which pipe to go through.

Comment: I marked yours as the answer since your first comment was actually what got the gears turning. I really appreciate your help and patience.

Answer (score 3):

When you cannot decide a type at compile time, perform a runtime type test, possibly in combination with the `as` pattern binding to a variable. Since we acquire type information, it would be wasteful to throw it away again, so we store it in some data structure.

For the encoding of sum types, here specifically any of `int16[][]`, `int32[][]` and `float32[][]`, F# offers a [discriminated union](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/discriminated-unions/).

```
type ArrayTypes =
| I16 of int16[][]
| I32 of int32[][]
| F32 of float32[][]

let arrayTypes : obj -> _ = function
| :? (int16[][]) as i16 -> I16 i16
| :? (int32[][]) as i32 -> I32 i32
| :? (float32[][]) as f32 -> F32 f32
| _ -> invalidOp "Unknown Array Type"

arrayTypes <| box[|[|0s;1s;2s|];[|3s;4s;5s|]|]
// val it : ArrayTypes = I16 [|[|0s; 1s; 2s|]; [|3s; 4s; 5s|]|]
arrayTypes <| box[|[|0;1;2|];[|3;4;5|]|]
// val it : ArrayTypes = I32 [|[|0; 1; 2|]; [|3; 4; 5|]|]
arrayTypes <| box[|[|0.f;1.f;2.f|];[|3.f;4.f;5.f|]|]
// val it : ArrayTypes = F32 [|[|0.0f; 1.0f; 2.0f|]; [|3.0f; 4.0f; 5.0f|]|]
```

Comment: I will try and edit my question further. I think you may be trying to tell me the thing I think I need, but I am new to strongly typed languages, so I'll tease it out a little more.

Comment: This isn't quite what I'm trying to do - this code seems to only work if an array of some numeric type is converted to bytes, and then converted back to the numeric array type. This code won't work if you feed it a naïve byte array. :(

Comment: Your edits are definitely helping point me in the right direction. The only hurdle now is how to get the elements from each of those DU cases. Unfortunately I have had no luck in implementing IEnumerable on ArrayTypes...